# flutter couldnt resolve all files for configuration classpath

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, build.gradle

well my project was working just fine and after i added SQFLITE package i started to get this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':sqflite'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :sqflite
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sqflite' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sqflite' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this happend to me about another package too and i ended up switching from that package to another but i really cant change this package and need to fix it.i tried changing the build.gradle file of the SQFLITE package and change this line:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:
to the version in my project build.gradle but that didnt fix it

Comment: Have you tried not to downgrade the sqflite plugin version, but upgrade your plugin version to the 7.4.2?

Comment: well not yet but im going to try it,tho i think that will cause my project some trouble,doesnt it effect other packages aswell ? like i think some of them also will aswell get this error after i update my application build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

The JDK version that 'sqflite' depends on conflicts with the JDK version specified by the Android project. Try the following:

1. Download and install JDK 11 (no need to configure environment variables)
2. Edit the file 'gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties' of the Android project.add
   `org.gradle.java.home=[your JDK 11 directory]` to the last line.

If you run the IDE on Windows platform, you need to add `\` before `:` and `\`
[image]
3. Click 'try again'